# How to make a link in R Markdown output to get a pdf or HTML with hyperlinks in text

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a data frame output in `R Markdown`. My problem is that the links column is very long and I would like to make hyperlinks in the column of text ("model" in this case) with the "link" column. In `R Markdown` it is possible to make a link in plain text but I don't know how to make it in a data output. I want to get a `pdf` or `HTML` file.

```
library (dplyr)
library (data.table)

data <- select(mtcars[1:4,], cyl, gear)
data <- setDT(data, keep.rownames = TRUE)
colnames(data) <-c("model","cyl","gear")
data$link <- paste('http://example.com/',data$model, sep = "")

data
            model cyl gear                              link
1:      Mazda RX4   6    4      http://example.com/Mazda RX4
2:  Mazda RX4 Wag   6    4  http://example.com/Mazda RX4 Wag
3:     Datsun 710   4    4     http://example.com/Datsun 710
4: Hornet 4 Drive   6    3 http://example.com/Hornet 4 Drive
```

I would like to get the model column with hyperlinks:

```
model                                      cyl    gear                             
[Mazda RX4](http://example.com/Mazda)        6       4      
[Mazda RX4 Wag](http://example.com/Mazda)    6       4  
[Datsun 710](http://example.com/Datsun)      4       4     
[Hornet 4 Drive](http://example.com/Hornet)  6       3
```

But when I do this in `R- Markdown` I have not results. Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you ultimately want to display the data frame in a knitted Rmd file, with the hyperlinks? Is the end goal to get a list of hyperlinks (regardless of data frame)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to work out your format, but you can have R Markdown print `results='asis'` in the chunk options:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library (dplyr)
library (data.table)

data <- select(mtcars[1:4,], cyl, gear)
data <- setDT(data, keep.rownames = TRUE)
colnames(data) <-c("model","cyl","gear")
data$link <- paste('http://example.com/',data$model, sep = "")
data$markdown_output <- paste0("[", data$model, "](",data$link, ")")
```

## R Markdown Output

```{r output, results='asis'}
data$markdown_output
```
````